# Как присвоить жанрам музыки вес в виде 0 или 1 на каждый жанр(присутствует или отсутствует)

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, статистика

У меня проект по машинному обучению, на классификацию жанров музыки и добавление их в БД, машину я уже обучил, и она уже предсказывает жанры, но только в массиве, поэтому я хочу присвоить жанрам вес в виде 0 или 1, чтобы по массиву программа мне выводила отсутствует или присутствует. На пример [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0...,0]

```
genres = 'blues classical country disco hiphop jazz metal pop reggae rock'.split()
file = open('data2.csv', 'w', newline='')
with file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
for filename in os.listdir(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/music'):
    songname = f'/content/drive/MyDrive/music/{filename}'
    y, sr = librosa.load(songname, mono=True, duration=30)
    chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr)
    rmse = librosa.feature.rms(y=y)
    spec_cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr)
    spec_bw = librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth(y=y, sr=sr)
    rolloff = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(y=y, sr=sr)
    zcr = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)
    to_append = f'{filename} {np.mean(chroma_stft)} {np.mean(rmse)} {np.mean(spec_cent)} {np.mean(spec_bw)} {np.mean(rolloff)} {np.mean(zcr)}'    
    for e in mfcc:
        to_append += f' {np.mean(e)}'
    file = open('data2.csv', 'a', newline='')
    with file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(to_append.split())
new_data.shape
new_data = new_data.drop(['filename'],axis=1)
genre_list = new_data.iloc[:, -1]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(genre_list)
X_new = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(new_data, dtype = float))
ynew = softmax(X_new)
print(ynew)
```

это то что оно выводит

```
[[0.0026979  0.00919354 0.00297058 0.00202884 0.00236537 0.00417573
  0.00427148 0.02581489 0.02394866 0.00905851 0.01048179 0.00299542
  0.00631784 0.01860214 0.00377617 0.00204791 0.00208164 0.00215192
  0.00219006 0.00226448 0.00250438 0.00199827 0.00558735 0.00240505
  0.00497674 0.00677883]
 [0.03046013 0.00227962 0.03192484 0.01345833 0.02737673 0.03365876
  0.00382085 0.00225602 0.00215641 0.00229429 0.00216659 0.00572082
  0.00279603 0.00200335 0.00432507 0.01282093 0.02204453 0.01069332
  0.01016923 0.00933927 0.00758227 0.01513128 0.00304784 0.00819185
  0.00333723 0.002673  ]
 [0.00667839 0.02618689 0.00578708 0.02009972 0.00847519 0.00390481
  0.0336273  0.0094236  0.01062719 0.02640737 0.02416675 0.03202684
  0.03106844 0.01472684 0.03360354 0.02090257 0.01195979 0.02385014
  0.02464251 0.0259507  0.0289022  0.01815095 0.03222784 0.02785633
  0.0330445  0.03028845]]
```

Comment: в приведенном вами примере данных максимальная вероятность - 3.4% и суммы значений в каждой строке не стремятся к единице. По определению `softmax` должен возвращать вероятности сумма значений которых для каждой строки стремится к единице. В общем с приведенными в вопросе данными вы получите матрицу нулей и поэтому непонятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def absolute(x):
    if x > 0.5: return 1 
    else: return 0 
def mapper(lis):
    return list(map(absolute, lis))
ynew_new = list(map(mapper, ynew))
```

Ну пожалуй как-нибудь так.

Comment: простите, но я возможно неправильно пояснил вопрос, [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0...,0], где первый 0-это жанр blues и он отсутствует, а 1 жанр classical и он присутствует, а данный массив, это предсказание машины, которое нужно перевести жанр, мне довольно трудно дается описание проблемы, поэтому если вы что то не поймете, не бейте сильно палками

Comment: @Андрей, для этого вы должны дать определение "присутствия" жанра - начиная с какого значения вероятности вы считаете, что "жанр присутствует"? PS в данном ответе используется пороговое значение 50% и поэтому все что меньше - будет означать "отсутствие жанра" в вашей терминологии.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно вероятность события конвертируют в предсказанное бинарное значение (`0` или `1`) путем сравнения с пороговым значением (`threshold`) и в большинстве случаев в качестве порогового значения используется `0.5`. Т.е. если вероятность события >= 50%, то значение вероятности округляется до `1`, в противном случае до `0`.

Судя по вашим данных, при таком подходе у вас могут получиться одни нули после округления:

```
In [143]: ynew
Out[143]:
array([[0.0026979 , 0.00919354, 0.00297058, 0.00202884, 0.00236537,
        0.00417573, 0.00427148, 0.02581489, 0.02394866, 0.00905851,
        0.01048179, 0.00299542, 0.00631784, 0.01860214, 0.00377617,
        0.00204791, 0.00208164, 0.00215192, 0.00219006, 0.00226448,
        0.00250438, 0.00199827, 0.00558735, 0.00240505, 0.00497674,
        0.00677883],
       [0.03046013, 0.00227962, 0.03192484, 0.01345833, 0.02737673,
        0.03365876, 0.00382085, 0.00225602, 0.00215641, 0.00229429,
        0.00216659, 0.00572082, 0.00279603, 0.00200335, 0.00432507,
        0.01282093, 0.02204453, 0.01069332, 0.01016923, 0.00933927,
        0.00758227, 0.01513128, 0.00304784, 0.00819185, 0.00333723,
        0.002673  ],
       [0.00667839, 0.02618689, 0.00578708, 0.02009972, 0.00847519,
        0.00390481, 0.0336273 , 0.0094236 , 0.01062719, 0.02640737,
        0.02416675, 0.03202684, 0.03106844, 0.01472684, 0.03360354,
        0.02090257, 0.01195979, 0.02385014, 0.02464251, 0.0259507 ,
        0.0289022 , 0.01815095, 0.03222784, 0.02785633, 0.0330445 ,
        0.03028845]])
```

максимальные значения по строкам

```
In [144]: ynew.max(axis=1)
Out[144]: array([0.02581489, 0.03365876, 0.0336273 ])
```

Т.е. в вашем случае максимальная вероятность составляет ~3.4% и если использовать 50% в качестве порогового значения вы получите матрицу, состоящую из одних нулей.

Дальше нужно определиться что же вы хотите получить на выходе с такими входными данными. Возможно вам следует "поиграться" с пороговым значением, пробуя разные величины и оценивая получившийся результат. Кроме этого из текста вопроса не совсем понятно - хотите ли вы получить только одну метку для каждого экземпляра или множество меток.

Универсальная функция для округления вероятности с учетом указанного порогового значения:

```
def proba_to_int(proba, threshold=0.5):
    return np.where(proba >= threshold, 1, 0)
```

Пример использования:

```
In [163]: proba_to_int(ynew, threshold=0.02)
Out[163]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

---

Если вам нужно выбрать номер столбца с максимальным значением вероятности, вне зависимости от порогового значения, тогда это можно сделать так:

```
In [145]: labels = np.argmax(ynew, axis=1)

In [146]: labels
Out[146]: array([7, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Я хочу получить несколько меток, о том, какой жанр отсутствует, а какой присутствует. И можно немного объяснить как мне дать определение присутствия жанра?

Comment: @Андрей, `как мне дать определение присутствия жанра` - вы должны принять решение - начиная с какой вероятности вы считаете, что жанр присутствует. После этого сравниваете вероятности с этим пороговым значением и получаете нули и единицы

Comment: Так, немного не то, у меня машина училась определять жанры по csv файлу, так как машинное обучение с учителем и модель машинного обучения готова, у меня есть песни, из которого машина извлекла данные по спектрограмме, но без жанра, и мне нужно, чтобы по данным извлеченным из песен, машина определила жанр, и данный массив оказался именно предсказанием машины, то есть эти цифры вместе и есть жанр, 1 массив-1 жанр, теперь мне надо выяснить, что это за жанр, извините, что туплю и трачу ваше время на то, чтобы просто понять мой вопрос, просто в данном случае я новичок(